# EventSource with Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventListener<? extends Event>> without unchecked call

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern, unchecked

I need to implement Observer pattern with List of listeners per Event class.

I have:

empty interface Event

```
public interface Event {}
```

interface for Listeners:

```
public interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
void handle(T event);

Class<T> getEventClass();}
```

and event source:

```
public class EventSource {
private final Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventListener<? extends Event>>> listeners = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void subscribe(EventListener<? extends Event> listener) {
    Class<? extends Event> eventClass = listener.getEventClass();
    if (!listeners.containsKey(eventClass)) {
        listeners.put(eventClass, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    listeners.get(eventClass).add(listener);
}

public void unsubscribe(EventListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener.getEventClass());
}

public void fire(Event event) {
    for (EventListener listener : listeners.get(event.getClass())) {
        listener.handle(event); //<-- Unchecked call to 'handle(T)' as a member of raw type...
    }
}}
```

It works, but I have "Unchecked call" warning. How to avoid it?

I tried:

```
public void fire(Event event) {
    for (EventListener<? extends Event> listener : listeners.get(event.getClass())) {
        listener.handle(event);//<-- compilation error
    }
}
```

but in this case I have "handle cannot be applied to..." compilation error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using NetBeans 7.4 I don't get your error but I do get: `incompatible types: ArrayList<Object> cannot be converted to List<EventListener<? extends Event>>`  under your `listeners.put(eventClass, new ArrayList<>());`

Comment: Thanks for advices. I understand the problem. In Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventListener<? extends Event>>> compiler does not know that "?" in Class and "?" in List are the same type. And I see not way how to tell it to compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "unchecked call" warning was reported for a good reason - you used the raw form of `EventListener`.  When you gave a type parameter `? extends Event`, it gave the compilation error because the compiler doesn't know which `Event` the `EventListener` handles - it only knows that it is a specific type of `Event`.  Likewise, it doesn't know the runtime type of `event` - it could be any specific type of `Event`.

The type must be known for this to make sense.  I would make `EventSource` generic, specifying the type of `Event` with a bounded generic type parameter.

```
class EventSource<E extends Event> {
```

Many `? extends Event` declarations will change to use `E`, e.g.

```
private final Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventListener<E>>> listeners = new HashMap<>();
```

There are many other declarations that will change to use `E`.

Now, `fire` will take an `E` so that it can be passed to `handle`:

```
public void fire(E event) {
   for (EventListener<E> listener : listeners.get(event.getClass())) {
      listener.handle(event); // Now this compiles
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't simply change <? extends Event> to <Event> cause in this case I will not be able to call subscribe() for subclasses of EventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
listeners.put(eventClass, new ArrayList<>());
```

to

```
listeners.put(eventClass, new ArrayList<EventListener<? extends Event>>());
```

I believe that will make the interface method `handle` behave as is supposed to

Comment: Thanks, but it changes nothing. In Java 7 <> (diamond) is auto substitution of EventListener<? extends Event>

Comment: @VitalyChibrikov I'm using Java 7 and the <> diamond operator is not defined on a LHS operator since you are just creating the ArrayList withing your `put` call. Therefore you must explicitly set it, otherwise the compiler will just infer is <Object>

Comment: Yes, you are right. listeners.put(eventClass, new ArrayList<>()); is 1.8 project level, not 1.7. In Java 7 I need full version of generic initialization, as you mentioned.