# Optimizing this event system

Tags: java, events, system

So I was reworking my Event System and I want to get it as optimized as possible. I have this down to about 82ms to fire 1 million events. I want to ask if there is anything you'd do differently and how to further optimize this? At the moment there is only some basic logic being done when an event is fired to the method, when I plan to use this for an upcoming project it will be a little more advanced which would probably double the execution time.

```
package me.xerces.eventbus;

import me.xerces.eventbus.annotation.EventHandler;
import me.xerces.eventbus.event.Event;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class EventManager {

    private ArrayList<Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle>> eventHandlerList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle>>();

    public void addEventListener(Object object)
    {
        for(Method method : object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
        {
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class))
            {
                Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle> eventHandleEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Class, EventHandle>(method.getParameterTypes()[0], new EventHandle(method, object));
                method.setAccessible(true);
                eventHandlerList.add(eventHandleEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addSpecificEventListener(Object object, Class eventClass)
    {
        for(Method method : object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
        {
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class) && method.getParameterTypes().length > 0 && method.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(eventClass))
            {
                Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle> eventHandleEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Class, EventHandle>(method.getParameterTypes()[0], new EventHandle(method, object));
                method.setAccessible(true);
                eventHandlerList.add(eventHandleEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeEventListener(Object object)
    {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle>> iterator = eventHandlerList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle> entry = iterator.next();
            if(entry.getValue().getMethodClass().equals(object))
                iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    public void fireEvent(Event event)
    {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle>> iterator = eventHandlerList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle> entry = iterator.next();
            if(entry.getKey().equals(event.getClass())) {
                try {
                    EventHandle eventHandle = entry.getValue();
                    eventHandle.getMethod().invoke(eventHandle.getMethodClass(), event);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Github link: https://github.com/X3rces/EventBus
EDIT: Is there a way to speed up when the JVM converts the invokation to a straight method call instead of using JNI?

Comment: My first thought is "why do you need so many events?"

Comment: the event system will be used for a game, evens will be fired before and after the game tick and the same for the render tick plus any extra events such as player movement. I used 1 million events simply to test how fast the event system was

Comment: Is 82ms for 1 million events sufficient performance?  If it is, then you're done.  If it's not, then run a profiler on it, find out where the hot spots are, and further optimize those.

Comment: The test im doing is checking if `if(processedEvents % 100000 == 0)` and then printing if true, when i properly use it the logic will be much more complex and most likely double or triple the execution time. I want to make the event system as optimized as possible before starting my project. What profiler would you suggest?

Comment: Why are you using Map.Entry<Class, EventHandle>. You realy do not need Map here. You can use Pair<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid

```
 if(entry.getKey().equals(event.getClass())) {
```

by using

```
private final Map<Class<?>, List<EventHandle>> eventHandlerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

See my EventSystem code in question

[EventSource with Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventListener<? extends Event>> without unchecked call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827435/eventsource-with-mapclass-extends-event-listeventlistener-extends-event)

Comment: Thanks, this reduced it down to a 14ms execution time.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your optimization! And I think it would be better to use Pair instead of Map.Entry. Not for performance, but for better readability of your code.